# Existe alguma alternativa para a diretiva OutputCache antes utilizada em páginas .aspx, para ser usada em páginas .cshtml em .net core?

Tags: .net, asp.net-core, aspx

Existe alguma alternativa para a diretiva OutputCache antes utilizada em páginas .aspx, para ser usada em páginas .cshtml em asp .net core ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No ASP.NET Core tem duas opções nesta estratégia de cache que você está procurando.

1. O *atributo* [ResponseCache](https://docs.microsoft.com/pt-br/aspnet/core/performance/caching/response?view=aspnetcore-2.2#responsecache-attribute) que você pode aplicar apenas nas Actions que retornam dados para a *View*. Assim, todos os elementos da *View* que são carregados a partir do retorno das `Actions`, estarão recuperando este retorno do cache.
2. [Cache Tag Helper](https://docs.microsoft.com/pt-br/aspnet/core/mvc/views/tag-helpers/built-in/cache-tag-helper?view=aspnetcore-2.2) aonde todo o conteúdo no seu *.cshtml* que estiver dentro da tag `<cache>`, estará sendo armazenado em *cache*.

Comment: Bacana, muito obrigado Raquel Pinheiro!

Comment: Por nada @RonaldoSampaio, até a próxima.